# Should I add Armoured Trucks to my passenger trains or run dedicated trains?

Tags: openttd

I'm wondering which is better?

Should I be adding valuable carriages to my existing passenger trains, to allow for faster turnaround and to add a boost of cash to my passenger services.

**OR**

Should I be running dedicated trains with 'unload all and wait for full load' so that I can gather larger numbers of cargo and generate potentially a larger profit?

Comment: It's impossible to tell without more information, but in general banks do not generate enough valuables for dedicated valuable trains to be economical

Comment: I usually find carrying valuables not cost effective (unless its the desert map with diamond mines).  I'd rather not deal with them at all and only deal in passenger/mail.

Comment: I've discovered with faster routes you often only need to add a single armoured van to turn more profit.

Comment: Personally, if I was doing city-to-city train services, you'd likely be better off running 100% passenger or 80% passenger and 20% mail and not worrying about the valuables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having done a little experimentation with this it looks to me like it's better to run valuables along with passengers and mail.

The rate of generation is too slow to make a full load viable on a single bank.